# Filter results of Azure storage directory list

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-cli

### Goal

Is there a way to (1) download every file named `index.json` in an Azure Storage container (in directories, subdirectories, sub-subdirectories, and on) and (2) rename each `index.json` with the name of its source directory?

### Proposed solution

I'm pursuing a solution that (1) uses `az storage fs file download` in the az CLI and (2) applies a wildcard or pattern that returns every `index.json` in every directory level of the container, but I am not successful with (2). See failed examples below.

### Current inefficient solution

My current solution is inefficient and doesn't return `index.json` from all levels of the container - only the top level.

I can add details around the use case if that will help. Thank you for any help or ideas on better approaches.

### Example of Azure Blob structure

```
container/

  product-1/
    articles/
      page-1.html
      page-2.html
    fonts/
      fontawesome.ttf
    images/
      product-image-1.png
      product-image-2.png
    node-modules/
      ...
    styles/
      style.css
      style.js
    index.html
    index.json

  product-2/
    articles/
      page-3.html
      page-4.html
    fonts/
      fontawesome.ttf
    images/
      product-image-3.png
      product-image-4.png
    node-modules/
      ...

    product-2-a/
      articles/
        page-3.html
        page-4.html
      fonts/
        fontawesome.ttf
      images/
        product-image-3.png
        product-image-4.png
      node-modules/
        ...
      styles/
        style.css
        style.js
      index.html
      index.json

    styles/
      style.css
      style.js
    index.html
    index.json

  index.html
```

#### Desired result (local machine) - each `.json` file is a renamed `index.json` file:

```
localIndexes/
  product-1.json
  product-2.json
  product-2-a.json
```

### Current undesirable strategy

1. Create a JSON file that is a list of all directories in the blob (note that it does not download subdirectories, sub-subdirectories, and so on, which is not desired).

```
az storage fs directory list -f wwwroot --recursive false --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $accountKey > dirs.json
```

**Result: dirs.json** (incomplete - just an example of objects included)

```
[
  {
    "contentLength": 0,
    "etag": "123",
    "group": "$abc",
    "isDirectory": true,
    "lastModified": "2022-01-13T23:20:19",
    "name": "product-1",
    "owner": "$abc",
    "permissions": "abc---"
  },
  {
    "contentLength": 0,
    "etag": "345",
    "group": "$abc",
    "isDirectory": true,
    "lastModified": "2022-01-13T23:20:19",
    "name": "product-2",
    "owner": "$abc",
    "permissions": "abc---"
  }
  {
    "contentLength": 0,
    "etag": "456",
    "group": "$abc",
    "isDirectory": true,
    "lastModified": "2022-01-13T23:20:19",
    "name": "styles",
    "owner": "$abc",
    "permissions": "abc---"
  }
]
```

2. Remove objects for each unneeded `.name` (aka directory) from `dirs.json` using jq. Using my inefficient method, the script in step 3 breaks if it encounters a directory that doesn't include `index.json`:

```
for excludeDir in css \
fonts \
images \
js \
node_modules \
styles ; do
jq --arg excludeDir $excludeDir '[.[] | select(.name != $excludeDir)]' dirs.json > temp.tmp && mv temp.tmp dirs.json
done
```

**Result: dirs.json** (incomplete - just an example of objects included)

```
[
  {
    "contentLength": 0,
    "etag": "123",
    "group": "$abc",
    "isDirectory": true,
    "lastModified": "2022-01-13T23:20:19",
    "name": "product-1",
    "owner": "$abc",
    "permissions": "abc---"
  },
  {
    "contentLength": 0,
    "etag": "345",
    "group": "$abc",
    "isDirectory": true,
    "lastModified": "2022-01-13T23:20:19",
    "name": "product-2",
    "owner": "$abc",
    "permissions": "abc---"
  }
]
```

3. Loop over each `.name` (aka directory) in `dirs.json` to (1) download `index.json` in that directory and (2) rename `index.json` with the name of the directory.

```
jq -r '.[] | "\(.name)"' dirs.json |
    while IFS="|" read -r name; do

for dir in $name ; do
blobName=`echo $name | tr -d '\r'`
az storage blob download --container-name $containerName --file localIndexes/$blobName.json --name $blobName/index.json --account-key $accountKey --account-name $storageAccountName
done

done
```

**Incomplete result**

Note that `product-2-a.json` is missing, as would further nested subdirectories.

```
localIndexes/
  product-1.json
  product-2.json
```

### Failed attempts at using the az CLI to download `index.json` using wildcards/patterns

Various iterations of:

```
az storage fs file download -p */index.json -f wwwroot --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $accountKey

az storage fs file download -p /**/index.json -f wwwroot --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $accountKey

az storage fs file download -p /--pattern index.json -f wwwroot --account-name $storageAccountName --account-key $accountKey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There is no specific File filter from Azure side. We need to fetch all the files and the files need to be filtered at client side based on requirement.*

*Different file types uploaded in Azure*

[image]

*Files fetching from azure using C# and Power shell script*

*Below is the Power shell script to fetch the files*

[image]

```
Install-Module Az.Storage
Connect-AzAccount
$MaxReturn = 20000
$Container_Name = "container_Name"
$Token = $Null
$Storage_Context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'storageaccount' -StorageAccountKey 'Key'
$Container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $Container_Name -Context $Storage_Context 
$Blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $Container_Name -MaxCount $MaxReturn  -ContinuationToken $Token -Context $Storage_Context
Echo $Blobs
```

*Below is the filtering of filetypes using C# code*

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
foreach (var blob in blobs)
        {
            if (blob is CloudBlockBlob)
            {
                var blob_FileName = blob.Uri.Segments.Last().Replace("%20", " ");
                var blob_FilePath = blob.Uri.AbsolutePath.Replace(blob.Container.Uri.AbsolutePath + "/", "").Replace("%20", " ");
                var blob_Path = blob_FilePath.Replace("/" + blob_FileName, "");
                blob_Infos.Add(new BlobFileInfo
                {
                    File = blob_FileName,
                    Path = blob_Path,
                    Blob_FilePath = blob_FilePath,
                    Blob = blob
                });
            }
            if (blob is CloudBlobDirectory)
            {
                var blob_Dir = blob.Uri.OriginalString.Replace(blob.Container.Uri.OriginalString + "/", "");
                blob_Dir = blob_Dir.Remove(blob_Dir.Length - 1);
                var subBlobs = ListFolderBlobs(containerName, blob_Dir);
                blob_Infos.AddRange(subBlobs);
            }
        }
        return blob_Infos;
```